# extracting values from matrix for sensitivity analysis

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm working on a sensitivity analysis based on some outputs from a model. Let's say I have a matrix as follows:

```
parameter_range <- matrix(c(1.61-(1.61*0.10),1.61,1.61+(1.61*0.10),            #parameter 1
                        20-(20*0.1),20,20+(20*0.1),                            #parameter 2
                        -2.5-(2.5*0.1),-2.5,-2.5+(2.5*0.1),                    #parameter 3
                        -1.007-(-1.007*0.1),-1.007,-1.007+(-1.007*0.1),        #parameter 4
                        4000-(4000*0.1),4000,4000+(4000*0.1)), nrow=3, ncol=5) #parameter 5 parameter

>parameter_range

      [,1] [,2]  [,3]    [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1.449   18 -2.75 -0.9063 3600
[2,] 1.610   20 -2.50 -1.0070 4000
[3,] 1.771   22 -2.25 -1.1077 4400
```

The dataset assumes that position [1,] = min value (mean value-10%) , [2,] = mean value, [3,] = max value (mean value+10%).

I need to create a loop to extract each possible parameter combination around the min and max values. This is 15 parameter combinations:

First combination:
1.449 20 -2.50 -1.0070 4000

Second combination:
1.610 20 -2.50 -1.0070 4000

Third combination:
1.771 20 -2.50 -1.0070 4000

Fourth combination:
1.610 18 -2.50 -1.0070 4000

... and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: Not clear what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

all_comb = parameter_range %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  expand.grid() %>%
  arrange(X1) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

**Result:**

```
> head(all_comb, 10)
         X1 X2    X3      X4   X5
 [1,] 1.449 18 -2.75 -0.9063 3600
 [2,] 1.449 20 -2.75 -0.9063 3600
 [3,] 1.449 22 -2.75 -0.9063 3600
 [4,] 1.449 18 -2.50 -0.9063 3600
 [5,] 1.449 20 -2.50 -0.9063 3600
 [6,] 1.449 22 -2.50 -0.9063 3600
 [7,] 1.449 18 -2.25 -0.9063 3600
 [8,] 1.449 20 -2.25 -0.9063 3600
 [9,] 1.449 22 -2.25 -0.9063 3600
[10,] 1.449 18 -2.75 -1.0070 3600
```